# DisplayName of nested class property in partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
public class ProductListViewModel {
   [Display(Name="Created Date Filter")]
   public FilterRange DateFilter {get;set;} = new FilterRange();

   [Display(Name="Last Updated Date Filter")]
   public FilterRange ModifiedDate {get;set;} = new FilterRange();
}

class FilterRange {
  public DateTime From {get;set;}
  public DateTime To{get;set;}
}
```

Each of the DateFilter property's is passed to a partial view. How do I get the display name from the partial view?

Answer (score 0):

I create `Farm` and `Animal` class. And I test it, it works for me.

**Result:**

[image]

## My code

```
public class Farm
{
    //[DisplayName("Cow")]
    [Display(Name = "Created Date Filter")]
    public Animal Cow1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pig")]
    public Animal Pig1 { get; set; }
}
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**My controller.**

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    Farm model = new Farm();
    model.Cow1 = new Animal { Name = "1111" };
    model.Pig1 = new Animal { Name = "2222" };
    return View(model);
}
```

**My View.**

[image]

[image]